# Assertion error while using cv2.matchTemplate in Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, bots

[This is the bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilRlg.png)

I am getting an assertion error while using a `bot.py`script that I am using for Runescape. I am learning how to use this tool, but when it came to improving the movements, this happened and I couldn't fix it so far.

I already tried some of the answers here on stackoverflow, but nothing worked so far.

I'm a beginner when it comes to programming and I am also new to stackoverflow.

This is the `bot.py` script:

```
    def __init__(self, window_offset, window_size):
        self.lock = Lock()

        self.window_offset = window_offset
        self.window_w = window_size[0]
        self.window_h = window_size[1]


        self.limestone_tooltip = cv.imread('limestone_tooltip.jpg', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

        self.state = BotState.INITIALIZING
        self.timestamp = time()

    def click_next_target(self):
        targets = self.targets_ordered_by_distance(self.targets)

        target_i = 0
        found_limestone = False
        while not found_limestone and target_i < len(targets):
            # if we stopped our script, exit this loop
            if self.stopped:
                break

            target_pos = targets[target_i]
            screen_x, screen_y = self.get_screen_position(target_pos)
            print('Moving mouse to x:{} y:{}'.format(screen_x, screen_y))
            if self.confirm_tooltip(target_pos):
                print('Click on confirmed target at x:{} y:{}'.format(screen_x, screen_y))
                found_limestone = True
                pyautogui.click()
                # save this position to the click history
                self.click_history.append(target_pos)
            target_i += 1

        return found_limestone

    def confirm_tooltip(self, target_position):
        result = cv.matchTemplate(self.screenshot, self.limestone_tooltip, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(result)
 object found
        if max_val >= self.TOOLTIP_MATCH_THRESHOLD:
            return True
        # print('Tooltip not found.')
        return False

    def get_screen_position(self, pos):
        return (pos[0] + self.window_offset[0], pos[1] + self.window_offset[1])
```

The error that I get is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\DEV\OpenCvTeste\teste_de_fogo\bot.py", line 227, in run
    success = self.click_next_target()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DEV\OpenCvTeste\teste_de_fogo\bot.py", line 90, in click_next_target
    if self.confirm_tooltip(target_pos):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DEV\OpenCvTeste\teste_de_fogo\bot.py", line 149, in confirm_tooltip
    result = cv.matchTemplate(self.screenshot, self.limestone_tooltip, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:1164: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::matchTemplate'
```

Comment: **(1/2)** It’s difficult to tell you exactly what’s the problem because: 1) That’s a lot of code, mostly irrelevant to your problem and 2) you are not sharing your images (which your program depends on to reproduce your results). Now, according to the error you report, the interpreter is complaining that `cv.matchTemplate` received wrong types in its arguments. This means that you passed a non-supported image to the function. Both images have to be either [32-bit or 8-bit.](https://docs.opencv.org/4.9.0/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga586ebfb0a7fb604b35a23d85391329be)

Comment: **(2/2)** Most likely you need an 8-bit image here (grayscale). Pass grayscales images to the function, you probably are feeding it BGR (24-bit) images. Convert to grayscale prior to that. Also note that the template (patch) must be smaller than the “target” image. Again, these are all assumptions because you are not providing all the resources needed to reproduce your error. Lastly, you can use [`cv.cvtColor()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.9.0/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab) to perform color conversion. Use the `cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` code.

Comment: **(extra)** Also beware that your numpy arrays are actual images and not `empty` arrays.

Comment: I posted the image, converted it to 8 bits, but I think it went wrong, the error continues
File "d:\DEV\OpenCvTeste\bot\bot.py", line 150, in confirm_tooltip
    result = cv.matchTemplate(self.screenshot, self.copper_tooltip, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:1164: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::matchTemplate'

Comment: what is the `dtype` of the arrays you are trying to feed the `cv.matchTemplate`

Comment: @TinoD there is no dtype declared

Comment: You only have one image. But where is the other second image? template = cv.imread(....) Here is link https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

Comment: @toyotaSupra The second image is a screenshot that is taken every moment